# Transferring data from folder to folder from Azure Blob Storage to Google Cloud Storage using Google Cloud Storage Transfer Service

Tags: cron, google-cloud-storage, azure-blob-storage, data-transfer

I have a number of different folders stored in different folders in a Blob Storage account on Azure, and have moved all the files in these folders to a equivalently named folder in a Cloud Storage bucket on Google Cloud. I have around 10 different storage folders in Azure. I would now like to schedule daily recurring transfer jobs from these Azure Blob folders, but wonder if there is a way to schedule only one job to move the data from these 10 folders to GCS, or if I am in need to schedule 10 different jobs to move files from each folder on Azure to the corresponding folder in GCS. Thank you in advance!

Regards,
Bertan

Answer (score 1):

Based on this documentation on [scheduling transfers](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/schedule-transfer-jobs):

> You can schedule your transfer jobs to run periodically, as frequently as every hour. Storage Transfer Service runs an incremental transfer at the frequency you specify, copying data to Cloud Storage, and recording the results of the transfer in the Google Cloud Console without human intervention.

Storage Transfer Service jobs support the following interval periods:

- Hours
- Days
- Weeks

You can also choose to start the transfer immediately or at a later time.

You may follow this link on [creating a transfer with scheduling options](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-transfers#create_a_transfer) if you want to create a new transfer or [manage transfers](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/manage-transfers) if you already have an existing transfer service so that you can edit the transfer schedule.

You can check these links for additional guides on transferring data:

- [Sources and sinks](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/sources-and-sinks)
- [Manage agent pools](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/on-prem-agent-pools)
- [Configure access to a source: Microsoft Azure Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/source-microsoft-azure)

Here's an example schedules:

| Scenario | How to configure your schedule |
| --- | --- |
| Copy data every night at midnight, forever | Run every day |
|  | Starting on |
|  | Start date/time—tonight at midnight |
|  | End date—None |
| Copy data every hour, starting now | Run with custom frequency |
|  | Starting now |
|  | End date—None |
|  | Custom frequency: Repeat every—1, Hours |
| Copy data every Tuesday at 3PM, starting in 2 weeks and stopping on April 3, 2030. | Run every week |
|  | Starting on |
|  | Start date/time—Tuesday 3:00PM, 2 weeks from now |
|  | End date—April 3, 2030 |

Screenshot:

[image: 7]